# Simple list menu with submenu is not working

Tags: html, nav, css

The code from below does not work, and submenu showing on page load, but it suppose to hide. Am I missing something here?

You can see the code at http://jsfiddle.net/x3yJ6/

CSS:

```
.menu > li{
    display: inline;
}

.menu > li{
    display none;
}

.menu > li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item a
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li>SubItem a</li>
        <li>Sub Item b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: typo: `display none;` in your second rule should be `display: none;`

Comment: and that rule *probably* wants to be `.menu > li ul`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x3yJ6/2/

Comment: And i spended 3 mins to find why display none doesn't work :P

Comment: Good thing for comments, the question edition was approved when the typo was fixed not by OP. I think this is actually counter intuitive since the original code was changed. Thank you Paul for changing it back

Comment: I undid that part of the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css with this below code

```
.menu .submenu{
    display: none;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3yJ6/4/)

First mistake `.menu > li` & Second mistake `display none;`

Answer (score 0):

2 Errors:

```
.submenu > li{
    display: none;
}
```